# Select each row of table except where the id is not the maximum value for a given foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

Given a table such as the following called form_letters:

```
+---------------+----+
| respondent_id | id |
+---------------+----+
|             3 |  1 |
|             7 |  2 |
|             7 |  3 |
+---------------+----+
```

How can I select each of these rows except the ones that do not have the maximum id value for a given respondent_id.

Example results:

```
+---------------+----+
| respondent_id | id |
+---------------+----+
|             3 |  1 |
|             7 |  3 |
+---------------+----+
```

Comment: `except the ones that do not have the maximum id` or having the the one with maximum id ?

Comment: more explain about question

Comment: I'd like to include the rows with the highest id for a given respondent_id and exclude the rows without the maximum id (for a given respondent_id, of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work;

```
SELECT respondent_id, MAX(id) as id FROM form_letters
group by respondent_id
```

MySQL fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5c4dc0/2

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of doing it. `group by` using `max()`, or using `not exits` and using `left join`

Here is using left join which is better in terms of performance on indexed columns

```
select 
f1.*
from form_letters f1
left join form_letters f2 on f1.respondent_id = f2.respondent_id
and f1.id < f2.id
where f2.respondent_id is null
```

Using `not exits`

```
select f1.*
from form_letters f1
where not exists
(
  select 1 from form_letters f2
  where f1.respondent_id = f2.respondent_id
  and f1.id < f2.id
)
```

**[Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b5735/3)**

Comment: I think the `not exists` should be `exists`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it.  Get the max id in a sub query, then join it back to your original table. Next, limit to records where the ID does not equal the max id.

Edit: Opposite of this.  limit to records where the ID = MaxID.  Code changed below.

```html
Select    FL.Respondent_ID, FL.ID, A.Max_ID
From      Form_Letters FL
left join (
   select    Respondent_ID, Max(ID) as Max_ID
   from      Form_Letters
   group by  Respondent_ID) A
on  FL.Respondent_ID = A.Respondent_ID
where FL.ID = A.Max_ID
```